# How is this string output possible?

Tags: java

I am unsure of how the following output is possible in the Java language. Notice the presence of the double dash in the output:

```
String keyName = projectId.AsString + "-comments-" + creationMomentString + "-" + _rand.nextInt() +  ".txt";
System.out.println(creationMomentString);
System.out.println(_rand.getClass());
System.out.println(keyName);
```

output:

```
0000001466400377645
class java.security.SecureRandom
o7grn3qt-comments-0000001466400377645--874329600.txt


-------------------------------------^
```

Comment: Seems like `creationMomentString` has a dash at the end of it.

Comment: @CodeBlind No it doesn't, the output shows the `creationMomentString` on the first line. The reason why is because `nextInt()` could have negative values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well ...

The call to

```
 _rand.nextInt()
```

returns an integer value. Integers can be negative. For example it could be

```
-874329600
```

thus producing the output you got.

The first minus sign is the textual output of your string concatenation. The second minus sign is the sign of the number.

Comment: Ug. My misunderstanding of the contract of nextInt(). I assumed 0 lower bound for some reason. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

[`Random.nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt--) can return a negative. What you're seeing is the `"-"` you explicitly put in, followed by a negative number.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely a minus sign from a value returned by Random().nextInt(). In Javadoc we can see:

> All 2^32 possible int values are produced with (approximately) equal probability.

Answer (score 0):

its not a double dash `(--)` as of you thinking about. the function `nextInt()` of class

```
java.security.SecureRandom
```

generate a Negative Unique Random Number which is `-874329600`.

So Your Complete String As File name will appered as `o7grn3qt-comments-0000001466400377645--874329600.txt`

like below abbreviation..

```
projectId.AsString + "-comments-" + creationMomentString + "-" + _rand.nextInt() +  ".txt";
   ||                     ||               ||                         ||              ||
o7grn3qt              -comments-    0000001466400377645     -    -874329600          .txt
```